# How to start learning KendoUI MVVM for best understanding with some projects?

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, kendo-ui

Can anyone help me out with some good Website or Books to learn Kendo UI  and have some ideas for projects in it?

How it is useful when compared to AngularJS/ReactJS?

Comment: I would honestly just start with reading their documentation(http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/mvvm/overview), explore their demos, and explore the source code for the demos.

Comment: there are no good resources for this. the kendo documentation and examples lacking details and do not demonstrate real world problems. From my experience it is the best to use kendo mvvm and do not mix it with other framework... Mixing it is really clunky.